# mod_wsgi and zeromq error (python)

Tags: python, web, mod-wsgi, zeromq

I am trying to make a search engine, running on the web. So I used mod_wsgi to get the query from the webpage by python. Then, I used zeromq to send the query to C++ searching program.

But the problem is, it seems zeromq and mod_wsgi does not work together. 
It is definitely true that python can import zmq (I tested it) but when it runs on the web, it shows error message that (actually an error log from apache)

```
File "D:/wsgi_app/wsgi_app.py", line 2, in <module>, referer: http://localhost/
         import zmq, referer: http://localhost/

File "D:\\util\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\zmq\\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>, referer: http://localhost/
         from zmq.utils import initthreads # initialize threads, referer: http://localhost/

ImportError: DLL load failed: \xc1\xf6\xc1\xa4\xb5\xc8 \xb8\xf0\xb5\xe2\xc0\xbb \xc3\xa3\xc0\xbb \xbc\xf6 \xbe\xf8\xbd\xc0\xb4\xcf\xb4\xd9., referer: http://localhost/
```

I have no idea why wsgi cannot import zmq. By the way the source below is complete python code

```
from cgi import parse_qs, escape
import zmq
def application( # It accepts two arguments:
      # environ points to a dictionary containing CGI like environment variables
      # which is filled by the server for each received request from the client
      environ,
      # start_response is a callback function supplied by the server
      # which will be used to send the HTTP status and headers to the server
      start_response):

    # get a query from the webpage :)
   data = parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])

   query = data.get('query', [''])[0]
   query = escape(query) #prevent script injection

   context = zmq.Context()
   socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
   socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:5555") #connect to C++ search server database
   socket.send (query)

   # build the response body possibly using the environ dictionary
   response_body = 'The request method was %s' % environ['REQUEST_METHOD']

   # HTTP response code and message
   status = '200 OK'

   # These are HTTP headers expected by the client.
   # They must be wrapped as a list of tupled pairs:
   # [(Header name, Header value)].
   response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
                       ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))]

   # Send them to the server using the supplied function
   start_response(status, response_headers)

   # Return the response body.
   # Notice it is wrapped in a list although it could be any iterable.
   return [response_body]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your wsgi script, explicitly add the location of your dependencies:

```
import site
site.addsitedir(path_to_zeromq)
```

Comment: import site
site.addsitedir("D:\\util\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\zmq")

I did like above

Comment: Drop the zmq from the end of the path you're using